# Lightbox loading content without being triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using one simple lightbox or you can call it modal window. It doesn't load any flash content until you click on the button PLAY and when you click on close, it stops the flash game (it actually stops as when you click PLAY again the game starts from beginning) 
BUT this is only about FIREFOX its not the behavior in CHROME, IE or Safari except MOZILLA FIREFOX all browser act in a complete different way which is opposite to the way I described above.

In chrome, IE, Safari maybe Opera the Flash content starts loading without being triggered (means if you don't click PLAY BUTTON still it loads) and even if you click on close button. Instead of stopping flash like in firefox the flash game continues to run (like being minimized instead of closed).

Why is this happening, How to resolve it, I am not able to understand this strange behavior?

RELEVANT CODES:
CSS:

```
#fade { 
    display: none; 
    background: #000;
    position: fixed; left: 0; top: 0;
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
    opacity: .80;
    z-index: 9999999;
}

.popup_block{
   width: 98.95%; height: 98.2%;
    display: none; 
    padding: 0px;
    line-height:1em;
    font-size: 1em;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px; left: 0px;
    z-index: 999999999;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #000;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #000;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.close {
    height:20px;
    float: right;
    margin: 0 2px 0 0;   
}
```

HTML:

```
<table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="tr-caption-container" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; text-align: center;"><tbody>
<tr><td style="text-align: center;"><a class="poplight" href="#?w=100%" rel="popup_name"><img alt="play game" class="happybutton" onmouseout="this.style.opacity=0.8;this.filters.alpha.opacity=80" onmouseover="this.style.opacity=1;this.filters.alpha.opacity=100" src="http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4084/4998558471_27e3985c16_m.jpg" style="opacity: 0.8;" /></a></td></tr>
</tbody></table>
<div class="popup_block" id="popup_name">
<div class="gamesharebuttons addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style ">
<a class="addthis_button_facebook_like" fb:like:layout="button_count"></a><a class="addthis_button_tweet"></a><a class="addthis_button_google_plusone" g:plusone:size="medium"></a><a class="addthis_button_more">Share</a></div>
<iframe id="myvideo" width="100%" height="98%" src="http://files.cryoffalcon.com/bhgames/Adventure/star%20island.html" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowTransparency="false"
></iframe>
</div>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    //When you click on a link with class of poplight and the href starts with a # 
    $('a.poplight[href^=#]').click(function() {
        var popID = $(this).attr('rel'); //Get Popup Name
        var popURL = $(this).attr('href'); //Get Popup href to define size

        //Pull Query &amp; Variables from href URL
        var query= popURL.split('?');
        var dim= query[1].split('&amp;');
        var popWidth = dim[0].split('=')[1]; //Gets the first query string value

        //Fade in the Popup and add close button
        $('#' + popID).fadeIn().css({ 'width': Number( popWidth ) }).prepend('<a href=";#"; title=";Close It"; class=";close";><img src=";http://files.cryoffalcon.com/bloghuts/images/close%20button.png"; alt=";Close"; width=";20"; height=";20"; /></a>');

        //Define margin for center alignment (vertical + horizontal) - we add 80 to the height/width to accomodate for the padding + border width defined in the css
        var popMargTop = ($('#' + popID).height() + 0) / 0;
        var popMargLeft = ($('#' + popID).width() + 0) / 0;

        //Apply Margin to Popup
        $('#' + popID).css({ 
            'margin-top' : -popMargTop,
            'margin-left' : -popMargLeft
        });

        //Fade in Background
        $('body').append('<div id=";fade";></div>'); //Add the fade layer to bottom of the body tag.
        $('#fade').css({'filter' : 'alpha(opacity=80)'}).fadeIn(); //Fade in the fade layer 

        return false;
    });


    //Close Popups and Fade Layer
    $('a.close, #fade').live('click', function() { //When clicking on the close or fade layer...
        $('#fade , .popup_block').fadeOut(function() {
            $('#fade, a.close').remove();  
    }); //fade them both out

        return false;
    });


});

</script>
```

HERE IS LIVE DEMO PAGE http://bloghutsbeta.blogspot.com/2012/04/fullscreen-testing.html

Comment: Please format your code correctly. That is giving me nightmares.

Comment: Some warning you were about to blast music through my speakers also would've been nice

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I hope now it is good to read

Comment: @JoshDavenport sorry about that, but you can see that's why I am here ^^

Comment: No one is smart enough here to help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `display:none` to the `iframe` that contains your flash doesn't seem to stop the flash from playing in the background so how about you remove it from the page, storing it in a variable to be added on demand. You look like you're going to have multiple lightboxes so you could store them in an object.

So on page load:

```
var popups = {};
$("a.poplight").each(function(){
  var $that = $("#" + $(this).attr('rel'));
  popups[$that.attr("id")] = $that.html(); //store the object in an object for later
  $that.html(""); //only empty it, don't remove it, so we can use it late
});
```

Then in your `$('a.poplight[href^=#]').click` call, before fading the popup in:

```
$('#' + popID).html(popups['#' + popID]);
```

Hope that works and I've been clear enough!

### Implemented

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var popups = {};
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a.poplight").each(function(){
       var $that = $("#" + $(this).attr('rel'));
       popups[$that.attr("id")] = $that.html(); //store the object in an object for later
       $that.html(""); //only empty it, don't remove it, so we can use it late
    });
    //When you click on a link with class of poplight and the href starts with a # 
    $('a.poplight[href^=#]').click(function() {
        var popID = $(this).attr('rel'); //Get Popup Name
        var popURL = $(this).attr('href'); //Get Popup href to define size

        //Pull Query &amp; Variables from href URL
        var query= popURL.split('?');
        var dim= query[1].split('&amp;');
        var popWidth = dim[0].split('=')[1]; //Gets the first query string value

        //Put the html back in
        $('#' + popID).html(popups['#' + popID]);

        //Fade in the Popup and add close button
        $('#' + popID).fadeIn().css({ 'width': Number( popWidth ) }).prepend('<a href=";#"; title=";Close It"; class=";close";><img src=";http://files.cryoffalcon.com/bloghuts/images/close%20button.png"; alt=";Close"; width=";20"; height=";20"; /></a>');

        //Define margin for center alignment (vertical + horizontal) - we add 80 to the height/width to accomodate for the padding + border width defined in the css
        var popMargTop = ($('#' + popID).height() + 0) / 0;
        var popMargLeft = ($('#' + popID).width() + 0) / 0;

        //Apply Margin to Popup
        $('#' + popID).css({ 
            'margin-top' : -popMargTop,
            'margin-left' : -popMargLeft
        });

        //Fade in Background
        $('body').append('<div id=";fade";></div>'); //Add the fade layer to bottom of the body tag.
        $('#fade').css({'filter' : 'alpha(opacity=80)'}).fadeIn(); //Fade in the fade layer 

        return false;
    });


    //Close Popups and Fade Layer
    $('a.close, #fade').live('click', function() { //When clicking on the close or fade layer...
        $('#fade , .popup_block').fadeOut(function() {
            $('#fade, a.close').remove();  
    }); //fade them both out

        return false;
    });


});

</script>
```

Comment: Let me use it and I will tell you right away if it resolves the issue or not ^^

Comment: OMG when I added your implement script and removed my previous one IT MADE THE PLAY BUTTON GO VANISH

Comment: Now that we don't have play button so no one is going to tease us hehehe ^^

Comment: @CryOfFaclon the selector `$(".poplight").each(function(){` here needs to refer to the elements that you're showing in your `click` event. Not exactly sure what that is, you're naturally going to be more informed than me on that

Comment: Edited to duplicate your ID retrieval from the `rel` attribute

Comment: well this is what that poplight is connected to, when you click on play it triggers it through this method <a class="poplight" href="#?w=100%" rel="popup_name"> w=100% is added to make it 100 percent in width

Comment: Now play button appeared but what has happened you can see it yourself

Comment: Okay, abandoned `.clone()` and opted to just grab the html and store that for later use instead. It's the same concept, just different execution. And done right..hopefully!

Comment: Well I used your edited code again but It is having same problem. I am thankful to you that you at least tried to help.